# How to draw the last fret with gchords package?

Tags: music

Is there a way to modify the gchords package output so that there is a horizontal line closing off the last fret?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gchords}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\mediumchords

\def\numfrets{4}

\chord{}{f2p3,n,f1p1,f3p3,f4p4,n}{Chord}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is no horizontal line closing off the bottom (fourth) fret.

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen the package but there is not a command for a horizontal line closing off the last fret.

Comment: Probably it could be added to line 274 of gchords.sty (I am not capable to do so), but this would be a very fundamental change, while it is not common to depict the last fret. With an open end it is always obvious where the first one is, even for right-handed players.